# LateInitializationError SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make a singleton of sharedpreferences, but I get a failure of not initialized

**(LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.))**.

I don't know what could be wrong. I suppose that it could be for the **late** of **SharedPreferences.dart**, or it lacks somewhere to define the initialization?

[image]

**Personaje_home.dart**

```
class PersonajeHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonajeHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PersonajeHomePage> createState() => _PersonajeHomePageState();
}

class _PersonajeHomePageState extends State<PersonajeHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var estiloTexto = EstiloTextos();
    final proPersonaje = Provider.of<PersonajeProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(proPersonaje.leerLvLPersonaje.toString()),                 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SharedPreferences.dart**

```
class SharedPrefsPersonaje {
  static final SharedPrefsPersonaje _instancia = SharedPrefsPersonaje._internal();

  factory SharedPrefsPersonaje() {
    return _instancia;
  }
  SharedPrefsPersonaje._internal();

  late SharedPreferences prefs;
  initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  int get readExpPersonaje {
    return prefs.getInt("experiencia_personaje") ?? 0;
  }

  set saveExpPersonaje(int value) {
    prefs.setInt("experiencia_personaje", value);
  }

  int get readLvLPersonaje {
    return prefs.getInt("nivel_personaje") ?? 0;
  }

  set saveLvLPersonaje(int value) {
    prefs.setInt("nivel_personaje", value);
  }

  void eliminar() {
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  inicializamosCargaDatos();
  runApp(AppState());
}

class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        //Cargamos datos del JSON, servidor
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => PersonajeProvider(),
          lazy: false,
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "My APP",
      initialRoute: "/",
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: "/",
          page: () => const PersonajeHomePage(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Future<void> inicializamosCargaDatos() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();
  await prefs.initPrefs();

}
```

**Provider_personajes.dart**

```
 class PersonajeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();

  int xpPersonaje = 0;
  int lvlPersonaje = 0;

  get leerXPPersonaje {
    if (prefs.readExpPersonaje != 0) {
      return xpPersonaje = prefs.readExpPersonaje;
    }
    return xpPersonaje;
  }

  set guardarXPPersonaje(int xp) {
    xpPersonaje = xp + xpPersonaje;
    prefs.saveExpPersonaje = xpPersonaje;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get leerLvLPersonaje {
    if (prefs.readLvLPersonaje != 0) {
      return lvlPersonaje = prefs.readLvLPersonaje;
    }
    return lvlPersonaje;
  }

  set guardarLvLPersonaje(int lvl) {
    lvlPersonaje = lvl + lvlPersonaje;
    prefs.saveLvLPersonaje = lvlPersonaje;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void borrarDatos() {
    prefs.eliminar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something similar to what you do when using firebase:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await inicializamosCargaDeDatos();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This way, you're making sure that nothing in your app is executed before your instance is initialized.

Comment: I didn't know I should have added async to **main()** and **await to initializeLoadData()**.  I thought that in the **future of initializamosCargaDatos** it was already enough with the async. Thank you very much, if you want to solve me the doubt it would be perfect, of why we should add to the main an async.

Comment: @Fumatamax I would recommend you to have some research about async await in dart. Basically, when you call inicializamosCargaDeDatos without using await, the compiler just executes this task while continues the execution of the next lines of code (runApp in this case). Using await tells the compiler "dude, wait until this function has completed before running the app"